# Error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Invalid provider type specified

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild

While building a .Net Framework project in Jenkins server with MsBuild VS16 I am getting the error below. As part click once code signing importing the .pfx file through power shell script.

> VisualStudioForApplicationsBuild target) C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(328,9):
>   error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Invalid provider type
>   specified.

Any suggestion on this error ?

Comment: Can you show a code here where the error occured?

Comment: Powershell script to import .pfx for click once code signing

$pfxpath = 'blah.pfx'
$password = 'test'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()

Comment: Below is the msbuild execution 

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin\MSBuild.exe"  ..\Sample.sln /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=ReleaseClient'